# Understanding Dockerfile CMD/ENTRYPOINT

Tags: docker, dockerfile, transmission-daemon

I'm new to Docker. Trying to build small image with Transmission.
Here is my **Dockerfile**:

```
#base image
FROM alpine:latest

#install Transmission
RUN apk update
RUN apk add transmission-daemon

#expose port
EXPOSE 9091

#start app
CMD ["/usr/bin/transmission-daemon"]
```

Then I start container:

```
docker run transmission
```

and it immediately quits. I supposed that it will stay running, as transmission-daemon should stay running.
I tried **ENTRYPOINT** also, but result is the same. However, next version works as expected:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/transmission-daemon"]
CMD ["-h"]
```

It runs, show Transmission help and quits.
What I am missing about how Docker runs apps inside containers?

Comment: compare with https://hub.docker.com/r/jess/transmission/~/dockerfile/ the last 2 lines are `ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/transmission-daemon"] CMD [ "--allowed", "127.*,10.*,192.168.*,172.16.*,172.17.*,172.18.*,172.19.*,172.20.*,172.21.*,172.22.*,172.23.*,172.24.*,17`

Comment: you say `It runs, show Transmission help and quits.` this is normal, you ask it to display the help, when done, it is over

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker keeps a container running as long as the process which the container starts is active. If your container starts a daemon when it runs, then the daemon start script is the process Docker watches. When that completes, the container exits - because Docker isn't watching the background process the script spawns.

Typically your `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` will run the interactive process rather than the daemonized version, and you let Docker take care of putting the container in the background with `docker run -d`. (The actual difference between `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` is about [giving users flexibility to run containers from your image in different ways](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#/entrypoint)).

It's worth checking the Docker Hub if you're looking at running an established app in a container. [There are a bunch of Transmission images on Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=transmission&starCount=0) which you can use directly, or check out their Dockerfiles to see how the image is built.